# Is Samuel Igra's "Germany's National Vice" reliable in any way?

Tags: nazi-germany

[This book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ia801603.us.archive.org/17/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.80851/2015.80851.Germanys-National-Vice.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiMprzwo7_1AhVKj4kEHTYXBhEQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1WPnW31t7o2wrvyHHDPtBz) originally published in German in 1945 is the primary source for widely publicized claims in the book The Pink Swastika that Adolf Hitler was a closeted homosexual and had a background in his youth as a male prostitute.

Is Igra even objective here? Has there ever been a long review of the claims in the book?

Comment: Like all similar publications, especially from that time, it is considered as crude propaganda without much historical significance, except itself being a sign of certain era.

Comment: Btw, this publication in some way is mirror image of German National-Socialist propaganda against Jews. In NS propaganda Jews were usually accused as being spreaders of homosexuality, perversion, immorality etc ... while Germans are described as moral and innocent people in their very nature. This author (being Jew) does the opposite - in his view German upper class is homosexual, depraved and degenerate while Jews are naturally moral and straightforward.

Comment: This question is adequately answered by searching for the title of the book on Wikipedia. As if calling homosexuality a 'vice' in the title were not enough to discredit this book, the idea that homosexuality is particularly prevalent in one or another country is ridiculous on its face.

Comment: @NeMo Calling homosexuality a vice is not enough to discredit a book. It was a prevalent opinion of that era, and even in this era in most countries of the world. It is a content of the book that discredits it, mostly because it uses sweeping generalization (Germans bad, Jews good) similar to NS propaganda ( Jews bad , Germans good).

Comment: I said that what discredits the book  is *titling* it with words to the effect that homosexuality is a vice. Notwithstanding that homophobia is wrong, a book from 70 years ago could contain both valuable insights and homophobia, if the homophobia was incidental to the insights. If homophobia is the central premise of the book, then the book is worthless; worth less than nothing, in fact.

Comment: @NeMo You personal opinion on what is wrong or right are irrelevant. This is History SE, and from historical perspective homosexuality and homosexualism were deemed as a vice (and worse) in the when the book was written.  What is important are proofs which this book is certainly lacking.

Comment: Great story. Unless you think this question is somehow salvageable, what's even your point here?

Answer (score 2):

### Lack of proof, hasty generalization

At the core of Igra's book is the question: "What caused the German militarism ?", one of the greatest evils in modern world (especially for Igra, him being a Jew). His answer, fully explained in last chapter of the book, is **homosexualism** - political, and even religious movement, satanic in nature, and devastating for human kind. According to Igra, homosexualism advocates reduction and even destruction of the family, considers women in general as inferior (good only for procreation) and advocates male bonding to the point of homosexuality as something heroic, reserved for elite. Igra alleges that National-Socialism was based on works of two obscure philosophers ([Hans Blüher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Bl%C3%BCher) and [Otto Weininger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Weininger), later being Jew himself) prominent for their contempt towards women, and advocating that true love could be directed only towards another male.

Igra starts his book with brief description of [Teutonic Knights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teutonic_Order), which he describes as first proponents of homosexualism among Germans. He explains that by their monastic vow to celibacy, which made them live among other males, made them prone to sexual deviations like homosexuality and drove them to sadism and destruction. As a proof for later he cites [Prussian Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_Crusade) which acquired them lands of Prussia, and made basis for Prussian nobility that latter created and dominated German Reich (before WW1). Igra alleges that even later Prussians, although no longer required to be celibate, also engaged in homosexualism, and cites example of [Frederick the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_the_Great) - supposedly homosexual, and later role model for Hitler.

Central part of the book revolves around [Eulenburg affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulenburg_affair). This was a huge homosexual and political scandal in German Reich. Several influential nobles close to [German Emperor Wilhelm II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_II,_German_Emperor) were outed as homosexual by the press, most prominent among them Wilhelm's close friend [Philipp, Prince of Eulenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philipp,_Prince_of_Eulenburg). Discovery was made by Jewish journalist [Maximilian Harden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilian_Harden), which Igra uses as a proof that only Jews (due to their supposed moral superiority) could be brave enough to fight evil of homosexualism. He also states this made Jews enemies of homosexual circles in Berlin, which later (in time of Hitler) led to their persecution and extermination.

Anyway, Igra alleges (without much proof) that Kaiser Wilhelm must have been homosexual himself, and that this affair (which largely died down by 1909) was main cause of WW1 in 1914. Supposedly, main cause for war was not economic situation or desire for more territories. Wilhelm simply wanted to shield himself and his entourage from scrutiny of ordinary German folk who would be appealed by perversions and decadence of the court, and he did that by diverting attention to war.

Then Igra goes into realm of imagination: At the time of affair Hitler was a pauper in Vienna. Since Hitler preferred German Reich to his native Austria-Hungary, Igra alleges that Viennese Jewish press coverage of said affair (which made Reich look bad and decadent) made him hate Jews. Sensing that this is not enough motivation, Igra alleges that in years before the war Hitler worked as male (homosexual) prostitute in Vienna, and was even acquainted with Eulenburg (which is practically impossible, since
Eulenburg was no longer ambassador in Vienna when Hitler arrived there) . Homosexuality being Hitler's big secret but also his big advantage since it opened him doors in upper circles, and made him acquainted with [Ernst Röhm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_R%C3%B6hm), but also with Krupp family, since [Friedrich Alfred Krupp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Alfred_Krupp) was supposedly homosexual (although he died in 1902).

According to Igra, [Night of the long knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives) in 1934 was attempt by Hitler to hide his homosexual past, since [von Hindenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_von_Hindenburg) discovered Röhm's homosexual tendencies and forced Hitler to remove him. In order to silence Röhm, he had him killed with added benefit of appearing anti-homosexual. Igra further alleges that Hitler (similar to Wilhelm) also started war in 1939 to divert attention from this affair in 1934. Finally, many in Hitler entourage were also homosexual, Igra mentions [Reinhard Heydrich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhard_Heydrich), [Baldur von Schirach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldur_von_Schirach) and [Emil Maurice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Maurice), with no proof. Third Reich laws against homosexuals and general punitive practice were never mentioned in the book.

Overall, whole book is a good example of [hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization), where with few examples author comes to wild and faulty conclusions, which are especially dangerous in political matters and could lead to death and devastation. It must be said that Igra's book in certain parts looks like mirror image of Hitler´s [Mein Kampf](https://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200601.txt), especially Chapters 2 and 3. In those chapters declares Jews as purveyors of obscenity, immorality, homosexualism and other perversions, based on few examples of indecent Jews in Vienna, while contrary to Igra, Germans are those naturally inclined to goodness and decency. This is actually sad, considering that two wrongs do not make one right, just more suffering in the world.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that Röhm's homosexuality was already public knowledge by [1931](https://www.queer.de/detail.php?article_id=38595) or, at the latest, [1932](https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/R%C3%B6hm_(Tucholsky)).

Comment: @Jan True, Igra claims that both Hindenburg and Mussolini were disgusted by that and put a pressure on Hitler to remove him for place of power.

Comment: Where did igra even get his sources if any?

Comment: @JacobBlaustein He mentions getting some records from police archives, supposedly from (Otto) Strasser, but these were never presented or cited in proper manner. So it is doubtful they exist. Other things that are verifiable are linked in my answer ( Eulenburg affair above all).

Comment: Good answer: this vision of one man able to create world wars from scratch just to be homosexual without being discovered is the first to any plot theories